# How to concise the following swift code like kotlin do?

Tags: swift

example swift code

```
func example(someInt:Int, someNullableInt:Int?)->String{
  let firstString = convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt)
  let secondString: String?
  if let nowItsNotNull = someNullableInt{
    secondString = convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(nowItsNotNull)
  } else {
    secondString = nil
  }
  return firstString.append(secondString ?? "")

}
```

while the Kotlin code can be more concise like below:

```kotlin
fun example(someInt:Int, someNullableInt:Int?):String = someNullableInt?.let{
 convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt)+convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(it)
  } ?: convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt)
```

How do I concise my swift code like the kotlin one?

Comment: Your Swift code doesn't compile either. I assume `secondStringNonNull` in the last line is a typo for `secondString`?

Comment: @Sweeper my bad, edited. But my point was the `?.let` part in kotlin

Comment: Hmm, the two snippets do different things, if the second parameter is not null. The swift snipped concats "firstsecond" whereas the kotlin snpped concats "secondfirst"

Comment: Null is not “null”; it is “nil” in Swift. And “nillable” is “optional”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?.let` translates to `map` in Swift, so the Kotlin code translates to:

```
func example(someInt:Int, someNullableInt:Int?) -> String {
    someNullableInt.map {
        convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt) +
        convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt($0)
    } ?? convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt)
}
```

This can be made shorter:

```
func example(someInt:Int, someNullableInt:Int?)->String{
    convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt) +
    (someNullableInt.map(convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt) ?? "")
}
```

Comment: `?.let translates to map in Swift` this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mingchen I suggest that you fix the typo (?) that derpirscher pointed in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68528091/how-to-concise-the-following-swift-code-like-kotlin-do#comment121109022_68528091).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is `Optional.reduce`, but that method is not included in the standard library. You will need to include it in your own package.

```swift
someNullableInt.reduce(convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt(someInt)) {
  convertAnIntegerToStringButTakesOnlyNonNullInt($1) + $0
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Modify a wrapped value if not `nil`.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - makeResult: arguments: (`resultWhenNil`, `self!`)
  /// - Returns: An unmodified value, when `nil`.
  func reduce<Result>(
    _ resultWhenNil: Result,
    _ makeResult: (_ resultWhenNil: Result, _ self: Wrapped) throws -> Result
  ) rethrows -> Result {
    try map { try makeResult(resultWhenNil, $0) }
    ?? resultWhenNil
  }
}
```